# Node-Red: AngularJs Geolocation in Dashboard Template UI

Tags: angularjs, node-red

I am trying to display my location through the Node-Red Dashboard UI Template with the following code, but without any success:

```
<script>
(function(scope) {
  scope.getLocation = function () {
    if (window.navigator.geolocation) {
      alert("Geolocation successfull");
      window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
      alert("Geolocation not supported");
    };
  };
  scope.showPosition = function(position) {
    alert("Lat Lon ok");
    scope.Lat = position.coords.latitude;
    scope.Lon = position.coords.longitude;
    };

})(scope);
</script>
```

Can anyone give an indication of what am I doing wrong? The first alert message "Geolocation successful" is triggered successfully, so I am assuming the `window.navigator.geolocation` is working. Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate on what this statement is supposed to do?
`getCurrentPosition(showPosition)` -- while there is a function called "showPosition" in the angular scope, that's not what you are passing as the arg.

Comment: I tried to adapt the following example to angular: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp